# Finding matrix wrt a different basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f : R^2 \to R^2$ be the linear map deﬁned by reﬂection in the line
$x+y = 0$.

(a) Find the matrix $A_f$ of $f$ with respect to the standard basis $S$.

I've done this part

(b) Find the matrix $A_f$ of $f$ with respect to the basis $S' = \{ (1,1)^t, (1,-1)^t)\}$

I found the coordinates of $S'$ with respect to my original $f$
and obtained that:

$f(1,1)^t$ = $(-1,-1)^t$

$f(1,-1)^t$ = $(1,-1)^t$

I'm then not really sure how to use these to obtain the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Using your equations, we have
$$\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
f(1,1)^\top  &=& (-1,-1)^\top &=& \color{blue}{-1}\cdot(1,1)^\top &+&\color{red}{0}\cdot(1,-1)^\top \\
f(1,-1)^\top &=& (1,-1)^\top  &=& \color{green}{0}\cdot(1,1)^\top &+&\color{orange}{1}\cdot(1,-1)^\top
\end{array}$$
The scalars that appear in the rows of these equations are exactly the columns of the matrix of $f$ relative to $S^\prime$:
$$
[f]_{S^\prime}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue}{-1}&\color{green}{0}\\\color{red}{0}&\color{orange}{1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Oh I understand now, it's the scalars you use! Great thank you for clearing that up!